# subtraction in bash doesn't work

Tags: bash

I have the following problem with a bash script:

```
validParameters=0
argumentLength=${#1}
argumentLength==$((argumentLength - 1))

#[code to increment validParameters]

if [[ $validParameters != argumentLength ]]
    then
        diff=$((argumentLength - validParameters))
        printf "Attention:\n$diff invalid argument(s) found!\n"
fi
    exit 1
```

The error happens in the line: `diff=$((argumentLength - validParameters))`

```
=3: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=3")
```

with the command `script.sh abc`

If I set diff to a fixed value (e.g. `diff=1`) instead of the subtraction, the script works perfectly.

Is my subtraction syntax somehow wrong?

Comment: The script you have posted does not produce that error.

Comment: I second TomFenech, impossible to reproduce your error, there is something important that you do not show. Your use of `[[` is quite strange. Use `[[ validParameters -ne argumentLength ]]` instead.

Comment: You're missing a dollar sign in `[[ $validParameters != argumentLength ]]`.

Comment: Syntax error: `argumentLength==$((argumentLength - 1))` (should only be one `=`). Voting to close as typo.

Comment: I forgot to copy over the line `argumentLength==$((argumentLength - 1))` with that line the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
argumentLength==$((argumentLength - 1))
```

You've got two `=`s here. It's equivalent to:

```
argumentLength="=$((argumentLength - 1))"
```

That's why the error message says `=3`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like one of the variables `argumentLength` and `validParameters` did *not* store a number, but something including the string `=3`.

For debugging, try to print both variables before subtracting them.

By the way, you can write `((diff = argumentLength - validParameters))`.

**Edit after your edit: Found the Bug**
There is one `=` too much in

```
argumentLength==$((argumentLength - 1))
```

write

```
argumentLength=$((argumentLength - 1))
```

or

```
(( argumentLength-- ))
```

instead.

Comment: Using `--` is non-standard, so might not work on other shells. The shortest thing to write would be `argumentLength=$(( ${#1} - 1 ))`.

Comment: @TomFenech I don't think the questioner cares about portability. He tagged the question as bash only and used `[[` which is also not portable.

Comment: Still, no harm in using portable syntax or at least specifying things that aren't, so that when someone blindly copies your code and it doesn't work on their system, they know why.

Comment: @Socowi The main point is, you don't need to separate the subtraction of 1 from the assignment to `argumentLength`, bypassing the need to use `--`.

Comment: Regularly pointing out bashisms in bash questions/answers would add a lot of noise. It'd be like pointing out vim-isms in vim questions. These days bash is a de facto standard. Anybody running a system old enough to lack bash ought to be smart enough to know their system is an outlier and they shouldn't be blindly copying anything off the Internet.